Rust Chrono parse date String, ParseError(NotEnough)
How to Convert a string like "2020-04-12 22:10:57 UTC" to Chrono::DateTime ?
Code：
#[test]
fn t() {
    let date_str = "2020-04-12 22:10:57 UTC";
    let datetime = DateTime::parse_from_str(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", datetime)
}

Error：
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseError(NotEnough)
thread 'types::date_time::t' panicked at src/types/date_time.rs:105:79:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseError(NotEnough)

How to convert a String to a chrono::DateTime

ParseError(NotEnough) means that your timestamp is too ambiguous for chrono to construct a DateTime. In this case, it seems that the timezone information is missing. Parsing timezone abbreviations is generally regarded as a challenging task. A single identifier may not be enough to uniquely identify a timezone. This likely causes the error you're getting
If you're certain that you need to be able to parse timestamps from different timezones, I recommend using %z (tz offset like +0000) instead of %Z (tz abbreviation like UTC). Otherwise, you could add the timezone manually (if you need it) like in the following code:
#[test]
fn parse_timestamp() {
    use chrono::NaiveDateTime;

    // Parse a timestamp without timezone information (`NaiveDateTime`)
    let date_str = "2020-04-12 22:10:57";
    let naive_date = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        .expect("Timestamps should conform to the used format");

    // Apply a timezone to the timestamp to get a proper `DateTime`
    // For other timezones, see `.and_local_timezone()` and the chrono_tz crate
    let date = naive_date.and_utc();
    println!("{:?}", date)
}

